# How do I get from an image::ImageBuffer to a actix_web::HttpResponse

Tags: rust, png, httpresponse, qr-code, actix-web

The goal is to generate a qr-code using the crate `qrcode` and send it immediately as a `png` file for download using actix-web

So far I have:

```
let qr = QrCode::new(&format!("http://example.com/{}", &link_id)).unwrap();
let png: ImageBuffer<Luma<u8>, Vec<u8>> = qr.render::<Luma<u8>>().build();
```

Which contains the qrcode. I can save this to a file using it's `.save()` method. But ideally I would not take that overhead and instead send the file immediately. However I fail to pass correct data to `actix-web`.

I tried the following which compiles but does send only a faulty image that cannot be viewed:

```
HttpResponse::Ok()
                .set(ContentType::png())
                .body(Bytes::from(png.into_raw()))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like so:

```
    let qr = QrCode::new("http://example.com/xyz").unwrap();
    let png: ImageBuffer<Luma<u8>, Vec<u8>> = qr.render::<Luma<u8>>().build();
    let mut w = Cursor::new(Vec::new());
    DynamicImage::ImageLuma8(png)
        .write_to(&mut w, ImageOutputFormat::Png)
        .unwrap();
    let vec = w.into_inner();
    // vec now contains the PNG bytes
```